# Nginx request_uri without args

Tags: regex, nginx

How do I get the value of `request_uri` without the args appended on the end. I know there is a `uri` variable but I need the original value as the Nginx documentation states:

**request_uri**

> This variable is equal to the *original* request URI as received from
>   the client including the args. It cannot be modified. Look at $uri for
>   the post-rewrite/altered URI. Does not include host name. Example:
>   "/foo/bar.php?arg=baz"

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're looking for $uri. It does not have $args. In fact, $request_uri is almost equivalent to $uri$args.

If you really want exactly $request_uri with the args stripped, you can do this.

```
local uri = string.gsub(ngx.var.request_uri, "?.*", "")
```

You will need to have lua available but that will do exactly what you're asking.

Comment: But as the question says, $uri may be modified by nginx (like when an error redirect occurs). So how to get the original request (such as in $request) but without args?

Comment: This answer is incorrect, though the lua fragment is correct. In the event of rewrites or `try_files`, etc. `$uri` will be changed to the path that nginx is currently testing/evaluating.

Comment: I was building my custom proxy cache key, this was useful.

Answer (score 34):

I use this map, which works without lua:

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
  "~^(?P<path>[^?]*)(\?.*)?$"  $path;
}
```

Comment: can you explain what is happening here. first time I'm seeing regex like this.

Comment: ~ (denotes this is a regex) ^ (anchors to beginning of url) ( (group/capture) ?P<path> (capture this group into the variable $path) [^?]* (0 or more characters that are not '?') ) (end group) (\?.*)? (Maybe a querystring, starting with '?' and possible more characters after that) $ (anchor end of url)

Comment: This is quite interesting, didn’t know nginx had named regex capture groups, unlike using `$1`

Comment: IMO this is a better answer because it works out-of-the-box without lua scripting, and for the same reason, I suspect it is faster - EDIT: just realised you already made that point, but I figure it's important enough to let the reinforcement stand

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer pointed me in the right direction, but I had to figure out where to add that directive, After some time investigating I found `set_by_lua_block`

```
set_by_lua_block $request_uri_path {
    return string.gsub(ngx.var.request_uri, "?.*", "")
}
```

I hope it saves some time to those who comes here.

Answer (score 2):

[Ryan Olson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43749234/771496) is really good but `map` cannot be used everywhere. It must be used in the `http` context.

If you need to get that information at a block level that does not accept the use of `map`, it can be done in a `if` statement. But remember that [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

```
set $new_uri "";
if ($request_uri ~ "^([^?]*)(\?.*)?$") {
    set $new_uri $1;
}
```

This code works out of the box (it does not use Lua or anything else).

Comment: I don't understand the observation on map. Map is defined once in the http block, then one simply uses the output of the map, as map are evaluated only on call. Thus there is no need of any if or additional constructs. If you have `map $request_uri $new_var` then simply use `$new_var` where needed.

Comment: @PierA I added some context as to where the `map` instruction can be used. Depending on what you are doing, you might not have access to the `http` context, for instance. By the way, it is not "additional constructs", it is an alternative way to `map` if your context does not allow it.

Comment: I see, if one is not allowed to change the http block, then yes. Thank you for the clarification.