# Set fastcgi_cache_key using original $request_uri without $args

Tags: wordpress, caching, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to integrate a WordPress plugin (Jetpack's Related Posts module) which adds query strings to the end of post URLs. I would like to cache URLs with FastCGI while completely ignoring the query strings/`$args`.

My current config is: `fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";`

I am aware of using [the solution mentioned here](http://community.rtcamp.com/t/using-fastcgi-cache-with-affiliate-tracking-software-lots-of-query-strings/2737) to turn my `$skip_cache` variable off for URLs containing a certain `$arg`, which works. However, I want to cache the same result regardless of the value of the `$args` rather than using a unique cache key for each set of `$args`.

I am also aware of [some suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084969/nginx-request-uri-without-args) to just use `$uri` in the `fastcgi_cache_key` rather than `$request_uri`; however, because `$uri` is not just the original requested URI minus the `$args`, something in the WordPress architecture (likely pretty links) forces all requested URIs to return the same cache result (rather than a different result for each page).

Is there any way to truly use the originally requested URI without including the `$args` in the cache key?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/545009/nginx-ignore-query-string-for-caching-certain-files

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just now, I had similar problem.
So, my solution:

In the nginx config add to the

```
http  { 
    ...
    map $request_uri $request_path { 
       ~(?<captured_path>[^?]*) $captured_path; 
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you will have a variable $request_path, which contains $request_uri without query_string.

So use $request_path for cache key

```
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_path"
```

Important. The "map" directive can be added only to "http {}". This directive will be execute for all requests for all hosts.