# Nginx fastcgi cache remove args from $request_uri to match $fastcgi_cache_key

Tags: caching, nginx

I am using nginx fastcgi cache but I now have traffic with /?keyword=blah+blah on the end of the request, the keywords are always changing so most requests are missing the cache and hitting php-fpm.

How can I make nginx ignore the query string when it is /?keyword= so it will just hit the cache as if without arguments, but skip cache for other args.

Example.
/topic1/page1/?keyword=apples
/topic1/page1/?keyword=laptops

The above urls should just hit the cache key for

/topic1/page1/

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880922/how-to-set-fastcgi-cache-key-using-original-request-uri-without-args) answer should work for you.

Comment: Thanks that and a little tweaking got it going