# FastCGI cache key while ignoring GET requests but allow certain GET requests to bypass cache

Tags: wordpress, caching, nginx

I have a WordPress installation running on with Woocommerce which requires the GET request `add_to_cart` to function in order for users to add items to the cart.

I have FastCGI cache key similar to 
[How to set fastcgi_cache_key using original $request_uri without $args?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38880922/how-to-set-fastcgi-cache-key-using-original-request-uri-without-args)

```
# Map request_path var without query strings
map $request_uri $request_path {
    ~(?<captured_path>[^?]*) $captured_path;
}

# FastCGI Cache
fastcgi_cache_path /var/run/nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=WORDPRESS:100m inactive=60m;
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_path$cookie_aelia_cs_selected_currency";
```

Is there any way to bypass FastCGI for these requests and for NGINX to just serve the page?

I am pretty new to NGINX and so any help would be very much appreciated

**UPDATE**

I have tried to use the following in the server block

```
if ($arg_name ~* "(add-to-cart|remove-item)") {
        set $no_cache 1;
}
```

The server is still ignoring this and serving the cached file.

**SOLVED NOW**

Answer (score 0):

Solved in the end by adding `.*add-to-cart.*` in the checks for request.

```
# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|.*add-to-cart.*") {
    set $no_cache 1;
}
```