# How to get request_uri without arguments on Nginx

Tags: nginx, query-string, nginx-location

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9084969/nginx-request-uri-without-args) already, but i need an advice how to put both needed parts together:

I need a following construction:

```
location ~*     {
if ($args ~ *)      {
add_header Link "<$scheme://$http_host$request_uri>; rel=\"canonical\"";
}
}
```

where `$request_uri` must be non-encoded url (can't use `$uri`). How is this way to get rid of `args`:

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
  "~^(?P<path>[^?]*)(\?.*)?$"  $path;
}
```

to get into my example?

Comment: Can you use `$request_uri` in the `if` statement instead of `$args` and capture the part you need while testing the tail?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find any good regex so I came up with this one:

```
^(?P<path>.*?)(\?.*)*$
```

You can use in your maps

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_no_parameters {
  "~^(?P<path>.*?)(\?.*)*$"  $path;
}
```

Here are my tests - https://regex101.com/r/K49bFm/2

Answer (score 0):

For those who'll need this later: the whole context looks like:

```
http {
        map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
        "~^(?P<path>[^?]*)(\?.*)?$" $path;
        }

        server {

                location ~* {
                if ($args ~ .) {
                add_header Link "<$scheme://$http_host$request_uri_path>; rel="canonical"";
                               }
                            }

              } 

     }
```